# Flutter geo fencing

Tags: flutter, geofencing

I need to implement geo fencing in flutter to book the restaurants and keep tracking of restaurants when app is also close and it should be run in the background can anyone suggest some good packages in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer your question, but I should point out that this isn't a very high quality question. You shouldn't ask for recommendations, and you should explain/show anything you have already tried.

In this case, two search terms would've led you to two pages that will probably answer your question: 'flutter geofencing'. These are:

- https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124
- https://pub.dev/packages/easy_geofencing

Comment: Looks like easy_geofencing can only implement a single geofence at a time. So not much use to most apps